# Fixed: Angular 9: Undecorated base classes that use Angular features

Tags: angular, typescript, mixins, angular9

I have recently updated to Angular v9 and as defined in the change-log, **it's deprecated to have an undecorated base class that uses Angular features or is extended by a directive or component.**

So I have many mixins in my application something like this:

**Destroy:**

```
export const Destroy = <T extends Constructor>(base: T = class {} as T) =>
  class extends base implements OnDestroy {
    destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.destroy$.next(true);
      this.destroy$.complete();
    }
  };
```

**Scroll:**

```
export const Scroll = <T extends Constructor>(base: T = class {
} as T) =>
  class extends base {
    public scrollToFirstError(form: FormGroup, scrollSelector?: string) {
      form.markAllAsTouched();
      const target = jQuery('.ng-invalid:not("form")').first();
      const scrollContainer = jQuery(scrollSelector || 'html,body');
      const subHeaderHeight = scrollSelector ? 0 : Number.parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
        .getPropertyValue('--height').trim(), 10);
      scrollContainer.animate(
        { scrollTop: jQuery(target).offset().top - jQuery(scrollContainer).offset().top - subHeaderHeight - 50 }, 'slow');
      target.focus();
    }
  };
```

Extending it in my component like,

```
export class ComponentA extends Destroy(Scroll)
```

and trying to access the properties of these mixins throws the following errors:

```
this.apiService.getData().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)... // Property 'destroy$' does not exist on type 'ComponentA'.


this.scrollToFirstError(this.form, '.modal'); // Property 'scrollToFirstError' does not exist on type 'ComponentA'.
```

Can anyone please help me with a suggestion to get it resolved? Thanks in advance!

******** **Update** *********

In my component:

```
export const MixinedClasses: any = Destroy(Scroll());

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-loan-list',
  templateUrl: './loan-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loan-list.component.scss']
})
export class Component extends MixinedClasses {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert `Destroy` and `Scroll` into @component decorated components and it should work fine.

Add:

```
// Destroy const becomes a decorated class
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-destroy'
})
export class Destroy implements OnDestroy{}

// Scroll const becomes a decorated class
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-scroll'
})
export class Scroll{}
```

This just an idea, you'll have to make it right for your particular implementation.

To be honest I don't quite follow the way you were extending them with passing `base` in as a parameter, so you might need to rethink the whole approach using standard classes.